# Equivalent of the block "From workspace" when it come to current/voltage sources

Tags: matlab, simulink

In matlab if you want to generate a signal in simulink based on an array/matrix in the workspace of matlab, you use **From Workspace** block.

My question :
I want to do the same thing, but i want to generate a current based of an array of values in Simpower System library, because the signal i want to generate is an actual current, so the block **From Workspace** doent work in my case (the output of the block can't be connected to my 3 phase voltage source). So what block is similar to **From Workspace** but can be a current source based on a variable in the workspace ?

Answer (score 1):

The library SimPowerSystems is part of Simscape. In Simscape library there is a block "PS-Simulink Converter". The block can be found under "Simscape → Foundation Library → Utilities" in Simulink Library Browser. The block performs the conversion from Simscape signals to Simulink signals. Connect the block "PS-Simulink Converter" to the Simscape signal (i.e. signal associated with the voltage source) and connect the block "From Workspace" to the output of the block "PS-Simulink Converter".

There is also a variety of alternative methods that you can use for data logging in Simscape. They are described in Simscape [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/data-logging.html).

Comment: To add to what was already said, you first need to convert your Simulink signal into a physical signal, and then connect the physical signal output to either a voltage source or a current source blocks. The single-phase version of those blocks is part of core Simscape, while the three-phase version of the blocks is part of SimPowerSystems (or Simscape Power Systems as it's now called). For older versions, it might be slightly different.